# How to add a hyperlink to textarea data in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I have a textarea where I need to add hyperlink to the text on click of a button. I am using jquery mobile.
My HTML Code:

```
<textarea rows="10" id="t1">Test</textarea>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="submit">Submit</a>
```

where as my Javascript:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit",function(){
   $("#submit").live("click",function(){
      var valu=$("#t1").val();
      alert(valu);
      $("<a href='#'>Adding</a>").appendTo("#t1");
   });
});
```

The hyperlink "Adding" is not getting appended to my textarea. Strange thing is that its working fine in IE7, but not in Chrome. Can someone please help me on this.

Note: I have tried taking

```
<a href='#'>Adding</a>
```

into a seperate variable and adding it to my textarea value and then converting it using .html() method of jquery. That is also not working.

Comment: I dont think it's possible to have a clickable hyperlink in textarea.

Comment: Ok, but it's working in IE7. Any idea why is it not working in Chrome?